# Heroku Node server: Possible to just serve plain HTML pages?

Tags: html, node.js, heroku

I was wondering if I could just upload a bunch of HTML (or any) files and have them reachable by URL, without specifying the routes, the static files, etc. The app is NodeJS/ExpressJS app, but I would like to serve some files and folders from that app like regular HTML pages.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just configure your directory as an Heroku PHP application by doing:

```
$ touch composer.json
```

and pushing that to your application. Heroku will now see your app as a PHP app and serve it directly, even though you only have static files.

Comment: And would that work only on some directories, or does entire app need to become a PHP app?

Comment: @Ska This is an application-wide setting.

Comment: Ok, so then basically it doesn't help me because I asked specifically for Node app (in the question text). Having a PHP app would net let me run Node anymore, unless I'm mistaken.

Comment: @ska you should have phrased your question to make that clearer. The answer depends on the web framework you're using for your project.